# Geometry Question about Triangle and Incircle .

Tags: geometry

What is the relationship between sides of a triangle and incircle? Also,how can I relate the side of the triangle and its angle?

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. The tangency points of the incircle split the sides of $ABC$ in segments with length $p-a,p-b,p-c$ with $p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$. Can you prove it?

Answer (score 2):

**PARTIAL SOLUTION:** Because tangent segments to a circle from a common point have equal length, you can say that
$$AF=AE$$
$$BD=BF$$
$$CE=CD$$
Now let us assign variables to these values so that
$$x=AF=AE$$
$$y=BD=BF$$
$$z=CE=CD$$
Then you can say that
$$x+y=AB$$
$$y+z=BC$$
$$x+z=AC$$
and then, since you are given the values for $AB$, $BC$, and $AC$, you can set up the following system of equations:
$$x+y=5$$
$$y+z=6$$
$$x+z=7$$
Do you see what to do from here?

Comment: It's easy now. Thanks

Comment: No problem! If you found it helpful, just $\uparrow$ and $\checkmark$!